# Using UICollectionView from another class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to write a class to that will display a collectionView.
I run into trouble when trying to add the collectionView as a subview to the UIView of the calling class. 
Is this possible?
Any insight is much appreciated.

The ViewController:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController{
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let editMenu = collection(view: view, xPos: 0, yPos: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
   }
}
```

and the collection view Class:

```
import UIKit
class collection: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {  
  var collectionView: UICollectionView?
  let cellIdentifier = "CellIdentifier"
  var myView = UIView()
  var xPos, yPos, width, height: CGFloat 
  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }  
  init(view: UIView, xPos: CGFloat, yPos: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
    self.myView = view
    self.xPos = xPos
    self.yPos = yPos
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    configureCollection()    
  }
  func configureCollection()
  {
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 00, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 80)   
    let frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, width, height)
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    collectionView!.dataSource = self
    collectionView!.delegate = self
    myView.addSubview(collectionView!)    //<- EXC_BAD_ACCESS    
  }
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
  } 
  func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
  }
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

    var textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height))
    textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    textLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkTextColor()
    textLabel.text = "Cell \(indexPath.row)"
    cell.contentView.addSubview(textLabel)

    return cell
  }
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    NSLog("selected \(indexPath.row)")
  }
}
```

Comment: I would say that is really bad, if your collectionview is contained in some other viewcontroller and you want to add the viewController's view to your current view, use UIViewController containment, making this view controller with collectionView as a childViewController

Comment: Why not use a Container View instead?

Comment: Please post exactly what kind of trouble you have experienced?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will look into UIViewController containment and post how it works out. Until now, I have only had one view done programmatically. Adding and hiding uiButtons and scrollViews has been fine. Not sure if this is "right" but it worked until I needed a collectionView.

Comment: @k6sandeep thanks for suggesting containment and childViewControllers. Ultimately, [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift) tutorial helped.